# jquery to remove H1 html snippet

Tags: jquery

I have a snippet of code I need to remove -

```
    <div class="l-titlebar-content"><h1 itemprop="headline">Text here</h1></div>
```

A previous question had this answer for removing an H1:

```
$("nobr.testClass > h1").remove();
```

so I tried to edit that and swap out the classes to:

```
$(".l-titlebar-content > h1").remove();
```

but it is not removing the H1.

Comment: And don't use `>` as it make the query engine look for direct children and in the markup you posted `nobr.testClass > h1` is not the direct parent.

Comment: `$(".l-titlebar-content > h1").remove();` should work if it's not working that mean you've another error somewhere in your code, try to check the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$(".l-titlebar-content h1").remove();` this will remove all H1 tag in element with class ***l-titlebar-content***

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, I am wondering if the itemprop is the issue

Comment: Can you tell me if you is using like that? `$(function(){
$(".l-titlebar-content h1").remove();
});`

Comment: I have: <script>
(function($){
$(".l-titlebar-content h1").remove();
})(jQuery);
</script>